# How to sync local database with remote server in flutter io

Tags: flutter

I want to develop an android application using flutter io framework. I do not know how to sync SQFlite database(local db) with MySQL database(remote database) in flutter Io

Comment: Have you already found an answers to your question? Because I would also be intersed in it.